# How can I compute the spin texture for a $SU(2)$ gauge model?

Tags: condensed-matter, gauge-theory, group-theory, spin-models

I am trying to determine the helicity of 4 Dirac cones in my model, and one way I want to approach it is by plotting the [spin-texture](https://www.google.com/search?as_epq=spin+texture). However, I am unsure of how one would calculate the spin-texture in the first place.

EDIT: I accidentally wrote chirality instead of helicity in the original post.